# Combining Arrays elements due to similar values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(
0 => headerOne:3
1 => headerTwo:5
2 => headerThree:6
3 => headerFour:3
4 => headerTwo:10
)
```

I have TWO elements that contain a string that starts with "headerTwo"
What I'm trying to do is to merge the elements where it starts with the same header and then ADD the integers from the string when they merge. So the end result would be like this:

```
array(
0 => headerOne:3
1 => headerTwo:15
2 => headerThree:6
3 => headerFour:3
)
```

I tried a number of ways, none of them seemed to have worked... and I have a feeling, that I've been doing it the wrong ways. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions should stand on there own, and your introduction didn't add anything to the content (and would have wasted valuable screen real-estate on the questions page where people are looking for quick info on your question!). Please refrain from using such introductions in the future, I have edited this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$input = array(
    'headerOne:3',
    'headerTwo:5',
    'headerThree:6',
    'headerFour:3',
    'headerTwo:10'
);
$temp   = array();
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $data) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $data);
    if (!isset($temp[$key])) {
        $temp[$key] = 0;
    }
    $temp[$key] += (int) $value;
}

foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
    $output[] = $key . ':' . $value;
}


var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'headerOne:3' (length=11)
  1 => string 'headerTwo:15' (length=12)
  2 => string 'headerThree:6' (length=13)
  3 => string 'headerFour:3' (length=12)
```

Comment: @Miss_New_Developer I've updated my answer - check it again please.

Comment: okay cool, i cant upvote since im new haha, but that's the answer ;)